# Can't Access Router. Empty Default Gateway

Tags: networking, router

I have a router connected to my Pc through Ethernet. I want to make some configurations, but i can't find router's ip address. 
1)I've tried ipconfig and the default gateway is empty.
2)I've also tried most commonly used router ips like 192.168.1.1

Can anyone tell me how can i access my router without reseting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up you Network Connection to get the settings via DHCP, then  look at your Network Connection details (or ipconfig /all cmd output) for DHCP server address. Most likely this is your router address